# How to call a function which is inside a function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to call a function inside a function to print c. There are two functions.

```
def ash():
    def jsh():
        k = 5
        j = k*5
        return j

    def ush():

        a = 5
        b = 6
        c = a + b
        return c

print(ush())
```

Comment: In a nutshell: you don't.

Comment: what is your real use case? this looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @deceze Please let us know why you need it. I think We can give better solution to you.

Answer (score 2):

You call it the same way you call anything.  Using the call syntax: `...(...)`.

Your challenge is having a reference to the object so you can call it.  The most obvious solution is to return the function.

```
def ash():
    def ush():
        a = 5
        b = 6
        c = a + b
        return c
    return ush

print(ash()())
# or
ush = ash()
print(ush())
```

Comment: At which point the question is of course why have `ash` at all… this is too artificial a use case to really give a useful answer.

Comment: What if there are two functions inside?

Comment: Return them both.